# Suppose $f : [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $g(x) : = x^2f(x)$ is a bounded function. Prove that $\int_1^\infty f$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Suppose $f : [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $g(x) : = x^2f(x)$ is a bounded function. Prove that $\int_1^\infty f$ converges.

I think that $f(x)$ should be $1/x^p$ for $p >2$ otherwise $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)$ diverges. In this case, the integral of $f$ converges by  p-test for integrals. But, I do not know how to formally prove the question. I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: $f(x)$ could be $\dfrac1{x^2}$ or \dfrac{\sin x}{x^2}$ or $0$; but what does the boundedness of $g(x)$ tell you about $f(x)$?

Comment: $f(x)$ could be $\dfrac1{x^2}$ or $\dfrac{\sin x}{x^2}$ or $0$; but what does the boundedness of $g(x)$ tell you about $f(x)$?

Comment: Is there some assumption that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @AJY there's no assumption for continuity

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think that  $f$ converges to $0$. But, this does not help to show $\int f$ converges.

Comment: What does it mean $g(x)$ is bounded?

Comment: I got it . Thanks.

Comment: @shk910 Without some such assumption on $f$, the statement is false. For example, consider the function $f$ where $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1/x^2 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \not \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases} ,$$ where $\int_1^R f(x) \mathrm {d} x$ is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s the first hint: If $g$ is bounded, then there exists a constant $0 \leq M < \infty$ such that $|g(x)| \leq M$ for all $x$. This means
$$|f(x)| \leq M / x^2 ,$$ and $\int_1^\infty 1/x^2 \mathrm{d} x$ converges.